# Ansible reading nested json values and matching variable

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath

I am using this in an Ansible playbook:

```
- name: Gather info from Vcenter
  vmware_vm_info:
    hostname: "{{ result_item.vcenter }}"
    username: "{{ ansible_username }}"
    password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
  register: vminfo
  loop: "{{ result.list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: result_item
```

I loop through a csv which has a list of VMs and their Vcenters.  The json output from the Ansible task is this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "changed": false,
      "virtual_machines": [
        {
          "guest_name": "Server1",
          "guest_fullname": "SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 (64-bit)",
          "power_state": "poweredOn",
          },
        {
          "guest_name": "Server2",
          "guest_fullname": "FreeBSD Pre-11 versions (64-bit)",
          "power_state": "poweredOn",
        },
```

Now I need to query this output for the VMs in my csv (guest_name matches vmname) and use set_fact to indicate whether the VMs in the csv are poweredOff or poweredOn.  Next I can use it as a conditional on whether to power off the VM or not based on its current status.

I can't seem to get the json_query to work when matching to the VM name in the csv to the json output and then getting the corresponding power status.  Any ideas?

CSV file:

```
vmname    vcenter  
Server1   Vcenter1  
Server2   Vcenter1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**set_fact to indicate whether the VMs in the CSV are powered off or powered on.**"*

A: For example

```yaml
    - read_csv:
        path: servers.csv
        dialect: excel-tab
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        servers: "{{ result.list|map(attribute='vmname')|list }}"
    - set_fact:
        virtual_machines: "{{ virtual_machines|default([]) +
                              [dict(_servers|zip(_values))] }}"
      loop: "{{ vminfo.results }}"
      vars:
        _servers: "{{ servers|intersect(_dict.keys()|list) }}"
        _values: "{{ _servers|map('extract',_dict)|list }}"
        _dict: "{{ item.virtual_machines|
                   items2dict(key_name='guest_name', value_name='power_state') }}"
    - debug:
        var: virtual_machines
```

gives

```yaml
  virtual_machines:
  - Server1: poweredOn
    Server2: poweredOn
```

Servers missing in the *vminfo.results* will be silently ignored.

---

Q: *"**Use it as a conditional on whether to power off the VM or not.**"*

A: For example Server1 in the first host

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Host={{ _host }} VM={{ _vm }} is poweredOn"
      when: virtual_machines[_host][_vm] == 'poweredOn'
      vars:
        _host: 0
        _vm: Server1
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Host=0 VM=Server1 is poweredOn
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, from your your example that you do have a [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values), so a tab separated values and not a CSV, which stands for *comma* separated values.

Based on this, the [`read_csv`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html) module, along with the `dialect: excel-tab` will help you read your TSV.

Then, you will need to use a [filter projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections) to query the JSON based on the data in your TSV file.

You could also need to [flatten the projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#flatten-projections) to get rid of the doubles list created by both the list in `results` and in `virtual_machines`.

An example of the resulting JMESPath query, for the `Server1` ends up being:

```
results[].virtual_machines[?
  guest_name == `Server1`
]|[]|[0].power_state
```

Then with all this in a playbook we do end up with:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - read_csv:
        path: servers.csv
        dialect: excel-tab
      register: servers
   
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          For {{ item.vmname }}, the state is {{ 
            vminfo | 
            json_query(
              'results[].virtual_machines[?
                guest_name == `' ~ item.vmname ~ '`
              ]|[]|[0].power_state'
            ) 
          }}
      loop: "{{ servers.list }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.vmname }}"
      vars:
        vminfo:
          results:
            - changed: false
              virtual_machines:
              - guest_name: Server1
                guest_fullname: SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 (64-bit)
                power_state: poweredOn
              - guest_name: Server2
                guest_fullname: FreeBSD Pre-11 versions (64-bit)
                power_state: poweredOn
```

Which yields the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [read_csv] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=Server1) => 
  msg: For Server1, the state is poweredOn
ok: [localhost] => (item=Server2) => 
  msg: For Server2, the state is poweredOn

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```